# True Test Error for LASSO

Tags: least-squares, lasso, mse

I have a data set which is split into a training set and a test set. Half is training and half is test. I apply OLS using lm in R, 10 fold Cross Validated LASSO and 10 fold Cross Validated RIDGE using cv.glmnet in R, and I find the MSE on the test data. I compare the MSEs and the LASSO has the smallest MSE. I want to know how will the estimated MSE on the test data for the LASSO compare to the true test error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the test data was not used to make *any* decisions about the model structure or hyperparmeters, the loss estimate on the test data is an unbiased point estimate of the expected true out of sample error for your chosen model.

If you used the test error of your three models to choose between the lasso, ridge, and unregularized model, then the resulting error point estimate for the chosen model is biased to be optimistic.  If you have no more data, there is nothing you can do to rectify this.

There is no way to observe the true out of sample error rate except in manufactured situations designed to investigate the properties of algorithms and procedures.  If you're doing real work on real data, you never really get to know.

If you would like some estimate of variability of your loss estimate, you may want to consider the [bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't use the test data to make any decisions about the model structure. Only the trainig set. Then I chose between the three models based on the MSE. I noticed that the MSEs are quite close to each other with the LASSO one being the smallest.